# Meteor: "ReferenceError: fs is not defined"

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteorite

Losing my mind with this one..

Getting "fs is not defined" on meteor when trying to read a file:

```
var data = fs.readFileSync(filepathHidden);
```

I have this package: `cfs:filesystem 0.1.2` on `Meteor 1.1.0.2`

Funny thing here is that if I write in *meteor shell* **fs** it prints object and it seems to have lot of functions etc stuff. But the thing here is that after writing **fs** in *meteor shell* my code starts to work!? And if I close meteor server and then start it again my server code keeps nagging until I run **fs** in *meteor shell*...

Can someone please explain what happens in this case? And how to achieve same thing in my code..

Comment: Do you have `fs = require('fs');` in the module somewhere? That module is not a built-in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to load it in via `npm`. In meteor that looks like:

```js
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
var data = fs.readFileSync(filepathHidden);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I have been struggling with this one something like 90minutes now.. I didn't know there is Npm thingie to use, tried just plain require.

Comment: I get `ReferenceError: Npm is not defined` I'm building the app with babel